# How do you display social media feeds in a unified design?

Tags: social-network

Our designer has asked us to create a section for the home page that will display the Twitter, Facebook, and Instagram feeds side-by-side. From her design and the discussions that followed, she would like the feed displays to all look similar. She brought up Smash Balloon for Wordpress. One, we're on Drupal and not on Wordpress and that does not exist for Drupal. Two, it's a paid plugin so I can't even see what it's doing. Three, if it's at all like ShareThis that ends up gathering data from end users, we can't do that. Am I purely looking at creating a custom solution with the providers' APIs or is there an existing Drupal solution? This is the requested design: [image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "questions asking how to implement a functionality or a layout seen in a site, for which just a description of the feature, a screenshot, or the link to the site where the functionality/layout has been seen is provided" are off topic here.

Comment: Is it off topic to want to know how to achieve something in Drupal? Yes a particular layout, but one that may require writing a module to access APIs or finding a module that exists?

Comment: The problem I see is that there's really no on topic part of your question. You seem to know that your options are 1. a third-party embed (off topic here for obvious reasons), 2. a contributed module (asking for a contributed module recommendation is also off topic here), or 3. building a custom module or modules to integrate with the APIs (specific questions relating to this are on topic, but you haven't currently asked any question related to this). See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: (Fwiw, I'd also love to know a nice, Drupal solution to "How do you display social media feeds in a unified design?")